# creating child object and passing parent as parameter on construct in PHP

Tags: php

When u create an child object and you want to pass a parent object as parameter on construct you can do like in the code below:

```
class parent {
  protected $x;
  protected $y;
  public function __construct($x, $y) {
    $this->x = $x;
    $this->y = $y;
  }
}

class child extends parent {
 protected $z;
 public function __construct($parent, $z) {
   parent::__construct($parent->x, $parent->y);
   $this->z = $z;
 }
}
```

but in this case i am just multiplying parent.

Is there any way to not copy parents data and append proper object? and code to look something like this:

```
class child extends parent {
 protected $z;
 public function __construct($parent, $z) {
   parent = $parent;
   $this->z = $z;
 }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to pass the parent as a parameter when constructing the child?

Comment: there is absolutely no need to do something like `parent::__construct($parent->x, $parent->y);`, i think you misunderstand inheritance

Comment: @disf.asia if you don't use parent::__construct you will have an child object that have $x and $y unseted. Of course you can construct your child passing all variables, having function like here  
`public function __construct($x, $y, $z) {
   parent::__construct($x, $y);
   $this->z = $z;
 }`
, but when you pass parent object, code is more clear, and easier to read

Comment: @treegarden because i need to have an child will all the information. As i wrote upper i can pass just variables, but to pass an object is more clear when you have many parameters in your class.

Comment: @costicaharea i get what you mean, but still I don't agree. In your question, `parent` refers to `$this`, I'm not sure you can overwrite it